# Problem from spivak's calculus singular cubes

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

For $r>0$ and $n$ an integer, define the singular $1$-cube $c_{r,n}:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2-0$ by $c_{r,n}(t)=(r\cos(2n\pi t),r\sin(2n\pi t))$. Show that there exists a singular $2$ cube $c:[0,1]^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2-0$ such that $c_{r_1,n}-c_{r_2,n}=\partial c$

I guess we have to consider the map that takes $[0,1]^2$ to torus and its boundary is bigger circle difference with smaller circle.. So, we then would have $c_{r_2,n}-c_{r_1,n}$..

Am i trying in correct way?

Can some one help me to make this more precise?

Comment: Let $c_n(s,t)= sc_{r_2,n}(t)+(1-s)c_{r_1,n}t$. $(s,t)\in [0,1]^2$ Note that $c_n: [0,1]^2\to \bf R^2 / \{0\}$ What is the   value of $c_n$ on the boundary of the square.